# How to get records from one JSP file to another JSP file?

Tags: java, jsp

I have two pages say one.jsp and two.jsp. tell how can transfer the whole details record from one page to other page.

one.jsp has fallow name as age records

```
       name             age 
     |  abc    |      |   8  |

     |  xyz    |      |  7   |
```

now i want to get these details in two.jsp, please tell me how can I do that.

Comment: Please add some code which you have tried for this.

Comment: How many records? only two? or even more?

Comment: Check my answer and `valObj`  will be a list if you have >1 records

Comment: not only two records . it dynamically generate number of records in jsp page I have to get each record value dynamically get into another jsp page.

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways to do that.

Setting attribute to `session` or setting attribute to `request`

```
session.setAttribute("SomeKey",valObj);
Object attribute = session.getAttribute("SomeKey");
```

or

```
    req.setAttribute("SomeKey",valObj);
    Object attribute2 = req.getAttribute("SomeKey");
```

Do not forget to casting to your required object.

Answer (score 0):

In jsp1 use this code..

```
session.setAttribute("user1.name","abc");
session.setAttribute("user1.age",8);
session.setAttribute("user2.name","xyz");
session.setAttribute("user2.age",7);
```

In jsp2 use this code..

```
String use1name = session.getAttribute("user1.name");
int user1age = Integer.parseInt(session.getAttribute("user1.age"));
String use2name = session.getAttribute("user2.name");
int user2age = Integer.parseInt(session.getAttribute("user2.age"));
```

You can also use request or application instead of session according to your use

Comment: this error is coming when i use this methos::::        method setAttribute in interface HttpSession cannot be applied to given types;
  required: String,Object
  found: String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: this code in jsp 1 works fine   <%
 session.setAttribute("user1.name", "Shammu");
 session.setAttribute("user1.age", 7);
%> and the code in jsp 2    <%=session.getAttribute("user1.name")%> 
<%=session.getAttribute("user1.age")%>

Answer (score 0):

Create another(third) column with hyperlink  tag. Create a link that will look like as

```
<a href="secondJspPage.jsp?name=abc&age=8">link</a>
```

Similar link will be created for each record on first JSP page.

When you click on that link you can get value in next JSP as: